# Is there a way to install Windows 10 in S mode in a VM?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10s

We want to start testing how some parts of our website work for [Windows 10 in S mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020089/windows-10-in-s-mode-faq) Edge users since there are sure to be differences due to the nature of our products.

But I can't figure out how to get Windows 10 in S mode without buying the hardware. Has anyone found a way to get Windows 10 in S mode running on a VM in something like VirtualBox?

Comment: Microsoft allows you to download free VMs with Window 7, 8, and 10 if you just need it for testing purposes. See [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). Takes two minutes to setup and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I have a Windows 10 VM, but I need a 10s VM. Right now it appears that the only way to get 10s is to either buy hardware, or to be a hardware supplier with a special agreement to install 10s. I haven't found any way to get 10s in a VM for testing.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I completely missed the "s" part.

Comment: You will have to create your own image.  Windows 10 S images are not distributed by Microsoft